# Specify environment variable needed

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, docker

I'm building a ReactJS app and I was wondering how can I specify the environment variables the application needs ? Where should I say "my app needs a DATABASE_URL variable that needs a string that looks *this* way and PORT that looks *this* way" etc ?
Is the Dockerfile enough ?

```
  environment:
    DATABASE_URL: mongodb://mongo/
```

Or should I use a specific file somewhere ?
Thanks !

Comment: You could make a `.env` file? I guess it depends on your setup and deployment strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where should I say "my app needs a DATABASE_URL variable that needs a string that looks this way and PORT that looks this way" etc ? Is the Dockerfile enough ?

- You can place it within your Dockerfile like so:

  ```
  ...
  ENV DATABASE_URL=mongodb://mongo/
  ENV PORT=1234
  ...
  ```
- You can insert it when running docker container directly like so:

  ```
  docker run .... -e "ENV DATABASE_URL=mongodb://mongo/" -e "PORT=1234" ...
  ```
- Depending on your actual need Dockerfile can be enough. Alternatively, you can define it through docker-compose or .env file included in setup depending on granularity of settings.

Comment: So putting it in the Dockerfile is enough ? Can I assume that any other dev that will use my app will check the Dockerfile to know the env variables ?

Comment: For devs that stands to reason (since they most probably need to build image based of that very Dockerfile locally) inspecting is usually a thing to do. Whether it is a good way of documenting it is another question altogether and depends on scope and target audience of your project...